# How to use `.bin` and `.json` output model from Tensorflow.js on React-Native Project

Tags: react-native, tensorflow.js

I want to create an application that have a camera which can detect object from what I trained.
I already have the model that contain `.bin` and `.json` files by following this repo : https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5 
which the result look like this: [image]

**The question is, how can I use this files on `React-Native` Project? Or any suggestion tutorial?** . I already try to find tutorial about it but can't find one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you load them just like you would without react-native. i suggest to start with pure js project and get the hang of tfjs and then move to react-native. the only difference between standard tfjs and tfjs-react-native are couple of platform-specific apis listed at https://js.tensorflow.org/api_react_native/0.8.0/

Comment: Thanks.. I'll try it